# How to display a message next to the mouse when on mousePressed event in swing?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I am trying to display a text box next to the mouse whenever it is clicked in a GUI. The same idea when you hover your mouse over a link on the internet, it shows a preview as a small popup bubble. I would like to have it when clicked.

Comment: Do you mean a [`ToolTipText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)

Comment: YES! Finally I found its name. How can I make it show on mouse event?

Comment: (1-) @Abdane, First, make an effort and read the tutorial!!! Download the working example and play with the code. Then ask a specific question if there is something about the code you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for you:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class CustomTip implements Runnable {

    private Popup popup;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CustomTip());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (popup != null) {
                    popup.hide();
                }
                JLabel text = new JLabel("You've clicked at: " + e.getPoint());
                popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(e.getComponent(), text, e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                popup.show();
            }
        });
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        frm.add(panel);
        frm.setSize(400, 300);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks ! :)