# Is there a way to create a JList in a modal dialog?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jdialog

I have a `JFrame` already visible. The user can load a saved session.

The idea is to create a `JList`, so the user can load the chosen session  and the frame can be updated.

The code bellow get a list of String and add them to the list.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list=new JList(model);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
try {
    for (String  part : Utils.getSessions()) {
        model.addElement(part);
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The next step : display the step.

What I found : add pane to the current frame

My Hope: display the list in a modal dialog

Is there a way to create a `JList` in a modal dialog?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139194/how-to-display-a-message-next-to-the-mouse-when-on-mousepressed-event-in-swing). In this example a `JLabel` is added to a popup, but you can add your scroller of `JList` instead.

Comment: Are you looking strictly for a popup (like a popup menu) or are you looking for a small modal dialog such as `JOptionPane`?

Comment: I am looking for  modal dialog, so I can see the content of the JFrame when the JList is visible. With JOptionPane, I can get only one String.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Huh .. I wondered if that (source) would somehow become a problem for mouse clicks in a list / scroll pane in a pop-up. Nope. Works just fine with a list.

Comment: *"I am looking for modal dialog"* Note that a nodal dialog would not only make a lot of sense, but it is quite different to the 'popup' as suggested in the question. Please [edit] the question to change that information. And a tip: Add @TadHarrison (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: BTW - what is holding you back from trying to display the list / scroll pane in a dialog? You don't seem to have made an attempt in the code snippet above. When you've tried that.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the `Utils.getSessions()`. Or get it from the JRE. e.g. for a `String[]` .. `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();` ..

Comment: *"Any help?"* [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: *"With JOptionPane, I can get only one String."* DYM the user of this app. might need to select two or more list items? In that case, you're on the right track by avoiding the `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `JOptionPane` already has list selection built on, no need to work with your own `JList`.

Here's the call to use: [JOptionPane.showInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-)

Here's a trivially simple example: [Displaying a dialog with a list of choices](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Todisplaysadialogwithalistofchoicesinadropdownlistbox.htm)

Here's a fully working example that lets you choose a font name (using the handy-dandy font list snippet given by Andrew in the comments).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ListChooserDemo extends JFrame {
  JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
  String lastChoice = null;

  public ListChooserDemo() {
    setTitle("List Chooser Demo");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    add(new JScrollPane(textPane), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JButton b = new JButton("Choose it!");
    textPane.setText("Click the button...");
    b.addActionListener(this::doChooseFont);
    buttonPanel.add(b);
  }

  public void doChooseFont(ActionEvent e) {
    // a handy way to get a nontrivial list of choices for a demo
    String[] choices = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

    // Show a list of options with no effort on our part.
    String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            this,                         // optional reference to frame/window or null
            "Choose a font...",           // prompt displayed over list
            "Font Chooser",               // title
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, // message style
            null,                         // Use default icon for message style
            choices,                      // array of choices
            lastChoice);                  // initial choice or null
    if (input == null) {
      // Handle case when user canceled, didn't select anything, or hit escape
      textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\r\nCanceled!");
    } else {
      // Do stuff that happens when a selection was made
      textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\r\nSelected " + input);
      lastChoice = input;
    }
  }

  public static final void main(String[] args) {
    // Run in GUI thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      ListChooserDemo frame = new ListChooserDemo();
      // Center in screen and show
      Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      frame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - frame.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - frame.getSize().height / 2);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOptionPane`'s ability to display any component. Use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, list);
```

to get a modal dialog displaying your `JList`. You can further customize this dialog by adding more parameters, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information.

A full example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

String[] options = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
JList<String> list = new JList<>(options);

// Shows the dialog
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, list);

// Do whatever you want with the selection, for example
frame.add(new JLabel(list.getSelectedValue()));
frame.pack();
```

Comment: `String[] options = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
for (String opt : options)
  model.addElement(opt);
JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);` could be shortened to `String[] options = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
JList<String> list = new JList<>(options);`